# Replace picture with css color and resize according to content

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS code which generates transparent div:

```
.camera_caption {
    position: relative;
    background: url(../images/capture_bg1.png) 0 0 repeat-x;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 263px;
    width: 717px;
    height: 234px;
    padding-left: 365px;
    font: normal 14px/24px 'Roboto';
    color: #fff;

}
```

As you can see the background is generated using this image:

[image]

But I have several problems with this solution:
I would like to use pure CSS code to display colorful background.
And also I would like to resize the background height according to content size. For example I have several lines of text in different languages. I need to dynamically to resize the background layer .camera_caption.

Can you propose me some solution of the problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not user as to what exactly your issue is and what is it that you want to get done.

But for auto resize you can remove the width and height given. Maybe you can have 100% width if that will be more appealing

```
width:100%;
```

If by any chance you need to have a minimum height and width you can get it done like this

```
min-height:500px;
min-width:500px;
```

Add background color with this code

```
background:blue;
```

**If you can elaborate or better post a fiddle, we can help better.**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use pure css, an online tool you may want to consider is http://duri.me/, which converts an uploaded image into base-64 encoding that you then include in your `css` class definition.  The end result looks like the example below.  Doing this, you don't need an image, because the value of the `background-image:url(data:...)` property *is* the image.  In your case, simply create your colorful background in an image editor, upload it, and grab the generated code.

There are goods and bads to this.  On the bright side, you don't have to worry about a missing image, **but** you're adding a lot of code (especially if it's a large image), and the "image" never gets cached.  You may also have to use a bit of javascript to dynamically resize the background, or, you can look into using the css property [background-resize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) to scale it appropriately.

```
.myImg {
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url(data:image/jpg;base64,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)
}
```